Why are x86 legacy instructions like BOUND or PUSHA not available in 64-bit mode?
Is there a reason why some legacy x86 instructions (BOUND, PUSHA, AAA, ...) cannot be used in 64-bit mode? Yes I know, that such instructions are only available for compatibility issues and should not be used in modern code.
One could argue: To reduce space on the die. But the space has already been used to make the commands executable. So the entire infrastructure is there for these commands. Why artificially limit the capabilities of the CPU?
I looked in an instruction reference, whether there are reasons given. Unfortunately there is only the information about which instructions are not available in 64-bit mode - not why.
For a few legacy instructions I found out that the opcode was reused in 64-bit mode. But this seems not to be the case for every "banned" instruction.

This question is similar to: Why BCD instructions were removed in AMD64?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The answer seems to be that they have outlived their usefulness, and the functions of those instructions are better done using other instructions. I think the BCD instructions actually date from earlier Intel chips from the handheld calculator era.

It was a convenient point in time to remove those during the introduction of x86-64. The opcodes may be reused later.

Say you have a house and you've been adding new rooms to it for 10 years. You decide, "Enough with this. I'll build a new house from scratch." Your decisions should be driven by "What parts of the old house do I like and want to keep in the new house?" Not "Let me take everything from the old house and then throw out the parts I don't like." If you use the second style of thinking, you end up just remodeling your old house. The fact that you built a new house means that you used the first way of thinking.

This should be answered with an authoritative source.  Everything else is opinion and speculation and should not be a comment, if anything at all.

In my view, a "why was this designed in this way?" question like this can be reasonably answered either with the designers' own statements about their actual rationale, or with a general explanation of the benefits of the chosen design relative to alternatives.  I've done the latter.

@RaymondChen: AArch64 was "new house from scratch". x86-64 was very much a remodel. I think AMD wasn't sure it would get catch on and get a lot of use so wanted to share transistors as much as possible including in the decoders, leading to decisions like setcc r/m8 still not zero-extending to fill a register, and cvtsi2sd xmm, r32 still merging into the destination reg so having a false dependency (K8 had half-width SIMD like PIII though.)  And they wanted to minimize required changes to toolchains and hand-written code to make it easier to convince people to support it.

@PeterCordes That's a new house that tries to preserve important things from the old house to avoid confusing the long-time residents (toolchains, like compilers). So you keep the kitchen very similar (but with higher quality appliances). On the other hand, you don't bother to carry forward the largely unused sewing room.

Opcode space is a valuable and scarce resource.  In some cases, as you say, the opcodes were reused for new instructions that were more useful.  Even where they were not reused at once, those opcodes became available for future use.
Note that "the infrastructure is there" only for the existing 16- and 32-bit versions of these instructions.  If they were going to make them available in 64-bit mode, one presumes they'd want them to have 64-bit versions (as was done for essentially all other instructions), and that needs at least some amount of transistors and engineering effort.
Also, keep in mind that the introduction of AMD64 (now called x86-64), circa 1999, was the first opportunity to break binary compatibility for 15 years, since the introduction of 32-bit mode with the 80386 in 1985.  I assume they expected (correctly) there wouldn't be another such opportunity for quite some time; indeed there hasn't been in the 25 years since.  So if they were ever going to get rid of these near-useless instructions, which served only to waste transistors and clutter the opcode space, that was the time to act boldly.  (Many people wish they had done so more boldly, and gotten rid of more of the inefficient or bizarre features of the x86 instruction set; but there was also a need to reuse the "existing infrastructure" where possible, to control costs.)
I would guess the AMD64 designers may have also hoped that someday, support for 16- and 32-bit modes could be deprecated and eventually dropped. At that point, the "existing infrastructure" would no longer be needed, and there would be a true savings in resources if 64-bit mode didn't need it either.  Unfortunately that day has still not arrived.

Do you have an authoritative source for your answer?

@fuz: No; I'm inferring the motivations of the designers from their actions, based on well-known history, common sense, and my own reasoning.  I have tried to clarify where I'm doing so.  Is there a particular factual assertion for which you think sourcing is needed?

Questions that are primarily opinion based are off topic on this site.  If we want to keep this one on topic, answers should be based on facts, not opinions.

IMHO processor design rationale is off-topic here. Only a handful of people could answer this authoritatively. None of them are active on Stackoverflow, best I know. What I recall from conversations with them while working at AMD during the genesis of x86-64 jibes with what is laid out here. The official Hot Chips presentation on x86-64 from 2002 lists "Eliminate unused/underutilized arcane x86 features within the context of 64-bit mode" as a design goal on slide 4; no further details are provided.

Besides what Nate wrote about freeing up opcode space, these two instructions were prime candidates to drop, requiring maybe significantly different microcode for the 64-bit version, unlike the BCD instructions like aaa which could have decoded identically in 64-bit mode if AMD hadn't wanted to free up that opcode space.
For pusha / popa specifically, having twice as many integer registers would make the microcode significantly different if they wanted a 64-bit version of it.  Or it would still only push/pop the "legacy" registers, RAX through RDI (including a spot for RSP which was always weird.)
And for bound to support 64-bit operand-size it would need to load two 64-bit values, unlike with 32-bit operand-size where one 64-bit load covers both halves of the bound.  (64-bit was the width of the data path from L1d to load execution units in K8, at least for FP/SIMD.  And also the widest width with guaranteed atomicity since P5 Pentium and since some AMD uarch.)
So it seems reasonable to drop even the 16 and 32-bit operand-size versions from 64-bit mode, especially since compilers don't use it.
But K7 and K8 run bound as 6 macro-ops (https://agner.org/optimize/), so it's not like they had a dedicated execution unit for it that would do both compares on halves of a 64-bit qword.  It might do two separate 32-bit loads, since it's documented as m32&32 not m64, so it might not actually get the atomicity guarantee.  In which case promoting it to 64-bit operand-size would have been no big deal.
Just a good choice to remove pretty much unused instructions in general, especially ones that were already slow so you could do the same thing just as fast with multiple simpler instructions.

AMD64 kept a lot of legacy baggage, avoiding giving any instructions different semantics in 64-bit mode, even when the old semantics sucked.  e.g. setcc r/m8 still doesn't zero-extend to fill a register (not until APX will we get a version that allows single-instruction FLAG to int, not just single-byte bool with a false dependency.)
And cvtsi2sd xmm, r32 and similar instructions still merge into the destination reg so have a false dependency.  (K8 had half-width SIMD like PIII though.)
AMD wanted to minimize required changes to toolchains and hand-written code to make it easier to convince people to support it.  Removing instructions that were extremely rarely used is not a big deal for that.  Changing semantics could be, for porting hand-written code or for changing compiler code-gen.
I think AMD wasn't sure it would get catch on and get a lot of use so wanted to share transistors as much as possible including in the decoders, hence the machine-code format just using REX prefixes for the new operand-size and more registers, still being a variable-length byte-stream which is hard to decode in parallel.
Any mode-dependent differences need extra transistors.
It was critically important that the first-gen AMD64 CPUs still be faster than Intel's in 32-bit legacy mode (and in compat sub-mode of long mode: 32-bit user-space under a 64-bit kernel), because the existing software ecosystem when they were first sold was 32-bit only.  Especially in the Windows world where it took many years for 64-bit executables to become common.
And if AMD64 hadn't gotten much traction from major software vendors like Microsoft, any extra transistors would be just dead weight.  (Costing power and die area for no benefit for 32-bit code.)
This is why AMD64's long mode machine-code format and instruction semantics are so similar to legacy mode, unlike with ARMv8's AArch64: most software running on ARM chips can be recompiled or rewritten, or (Android) is partly Java so can be JITed on new hardware.  AArch64 has a totally different machine-code format, significant differences in SIMD semantics (narrower vector registers are just the bottoms of full vectors, vs. 32-bit mode having each q vector made of two d halves, like x86's partial-register shenanigans.)  And even different instruction mnemonics and syntax for SIMD instructions, like vadd vs. add.
Besides, ARM is a RISC ISA so the decoders weren't as expensive in the first place.  Having totally separate decoders for ARM32 / Thumb / AArch64 all able to feed the same back-end isn't a big extra cost in area.  And techniques like power-gating or at least clock-gating currently-unused parts of a chip to save power was a well-known technique when AArch64 was designed in the early 2010s, but I think not a decade earlier when AMD64 was being designed.
In the early 2000s when AMD64 was new, dynamic frequency and voltage was barely a thing, and desktop was the major market, laptops somewhat secondary.  And transistor budgets were smaller, and we hadn't really hit the "power wall" of power-density per area being a limiting factor yet so power-saving wasn't a performance boost for desktops.  So putting in extra transistors to save power by halting the clock to unused portions of logic was probably not much of a thing yet.
